# Binding to a dictionary

Tags: wpf, mvvm, observablecollection, ivalueconverter

I think I have a rather interesting problem. I have a model where the main data structure really needs to be a dictionary. 
I want to bind the values of that dictionary to a listbox. 
I have an ObservableDictionary class that fires collection changed events when necessary.
Unfortunately if I bind to this observable dictionary, the listbox is populated with KeyValuePairs and I can't make an IValueConverter for it because KeyValuePairs aren't objects, they're structs. 
Is there some way in xaml to specify that I want the .value of all the Pairs?

If I just return the values of the Dictionary in the property I'm binding to, that list isn't observable and so doesn't update with the dictionary.
Is there a way to use INotifyPropertyChanged to force the UI to update when binding to a collection?

Thanks!

Comment: `KeyValuePairs aren't objects` 'tis a lie! Also: How is them being structs a problem for a ValueConverter?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DisplayMemberPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx) or [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx).